# get specific value of a TD tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

How can I hide a specific TD in my Table ?

Rendered page:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Codigo</th>
    <th>Tipo</th>
    <th>(L/V)</th>
    <th>Endereco</th>
    <th>Propostas Ativas</th>
    <th>Cons</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>373054</td>
    <td>Apartamento</td>
    <td>V</td>
    <td>Rua DO FURQUIM</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

ASP page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdImoveis" Width="100%" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSourceID="dsGrid" OnRowDataBound="grdImoveis_DataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Código" DataField="Imovel_Id" />            
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Tipo" DataField="TipoDsc1" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="(L/V)" DataField="TransacaoSigla" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Endereco">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("Descricao") %> <%# Eval("Logradouro") %>, <%# Eval("Numero") %> - <%# Eval("Expr1") %> <%# Eval("Complemento") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Propostas Ativas" DataField="NumeroProposta" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cons" DataField="FoundInSanNegocio" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Drawing (Example):**

```
Código      Tipo          (L/V)      Endereço         Propostas Ativas        Cons
373054      Apartamento    V         Rua Do Furquim   1                       0
```

I want to get via JQuery the value of the last column (Cons), but the user can't see this column. How can I hide and get the value of this column in each line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#<%=grdImoveis.ClientID %>').find('tr').each(function(){
      $(this).find('td:last').hide();
    });
  });
```

To get the value on click or some other event you can use:

```
 var value= $(this).find('td:last').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your Cons column is always the last one of your table, this should do it:

```
var myVar = '';
var myArray = new Array();

$('tr').each(function() {
    //this fetches the text content of the last cell of the current row:
    myVar = $(this).children("td:last").text();
    //this puts that value at the end of the myArray array
    myArray.push(myVar);
    //this hides that td
    $(this).children("td:last").hide();
});
```

I made a jsfiddle for it, seems to work.
http://jsfiddle.net/qnvHM/

Answer (score 0):

Check what the ID of you table is. Assuming it's `grdImoveis`, then:

```
// Hide last column and and get its value (text)
var comp = $("#grdImoveis TD:last").hide().text();
```

Comment: But, with this code, just the last data in my grid will be hide. I want hide all this column and get the value of each line